# Pi Filter Calculation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, filter

Here is my circuit schematic below. PT4115 feeds LEDs. Load current is 200-215mA and switching frequency is 500kHZ. How do i calculate pi filter or what is the best values for pi filter in this design ?[image]

Comment: First explain why you need a pi filter and where it goes in the schematic.

Comment: İ will put pi filter to input. Because this product gonna go EMC test. @Andy aka

Comment: *what is the best values for pi filter in this design* There is no "best", a filter is always a compromise between complexity/price/performance. There are so many dependencies that en "exact" solution is usually impossible to find. What is often done is: see what other designs use, then do the same. Test EMC, if not OK then see how filter can be improved.

Comment: Okey i will start like this. @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+0.000005+5+50+5+50%0A%25+0+693144843.1551454%0Ac+304+208+304+80+0+1.0000000000000002e-10+0%0Ar+352+80+352+208+0+10%0AO+352+80+464+80+0%0Ag+352+208+352+240+0%0A170+144+80+128+32+3+20+1000+5+0.1%0Ac+192+80+192+208+0+1.0000000000000002e-10+0%0Al+192+80+304+80+0+0.000001+0.0012275237561111727%0Ar+192+80+144+80+0+1%0Aw+352+208+304+208+0%0Aw+352+80+304+80+0%0Aw+304+208+192+208+0%0Ao+4+16+0+34+5+0.00009765625+0+-1+in%0Ao+2+16+0+34+2.5+0.00009765625+1+-1+out%0A

Comment: This is really useful thank you. @Sunnyskyguy EE75